# 12x24" Porcelain Tile over 2x6x1.5" T&G Spanning 48" Beams

Tags: bathroom, tile, subfloor, underlayment, deflection

I have some questions in regards to installing 12x24" porcelain tile over 1/2" plywood underlayment that sits above 2x6x1.5" T&G subfloor that is supported by posts and beams on 48" centers.

Actually, there is [an almost identical question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160818/tile-over-2x6x1-5-tg-subfloor-spanning-48-beams?newreg=6ac45bb716c743b199fffdda74cd0092) from a few years ago that summarizes almost all of my questions (thanks El Jay!). I even currently have 5/8" particle board under the carpet (yes, carpet in the master bath... 1974 build original!) like the OP did. However, I will be replacing it with plywood.

**My question is if the fix in the link still valid today?**

Quick summary of fix/plan:

1. Double hung 2x6's that span the 48" and do this every 16" OC? Or is that too close?
2. 2x6" blocks 16" OC in between the double hung 2x6's.
3. Do #'s 1 and 2 for entire area under the bathroom.
4. Screw into blocks and joists from above through the 2x6 T&G.
5. Self Leveler if needed (I think it will be)
6. 1/2" plywood on top of 2x6 T&G.
7. Schluter ditra on plywood
8. 12x24 porcelain tile

[image: rough sketch of proposed flooring system]
<sup>Imaged sourced from question linked above</sup>

We have redone the flooring in the rest of the house and the subfloor is very solid. I can not get it to bow or move. However, I want to be on the safe side and make this as strong as possible especially if I need to add self leveler.

**Would my above plan work or would you recommend going another route?**

Comment: Why would that not be valid? Are you concerned about code changes since then?

Comment: Are you planning on using joist hangers?

Comment: @FreeMan I am not necessarily concerned about code. I am more concerned that I am doing it the best way possible and not missing anything. Or that I am doing too much! ha

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Yes, my plan is to use joist hangers for both the blocks and joists.